I get The given data was not valid JSON when I enter an empty data to the login form
I get The given data was not valid JSON when I enter an empty data to the login form , but expected to return "The password or mobile field is required.", as in backend , but I get :
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unexpected character '<' around line 1, column 1." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unexpected character '<' around line 1, column 1., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0})))
struct AuthenticationResponse: Codable {
    let status: Bool
    let message: String
    let data: AuthenticationUserData?
}

class AuthenticationService: AuthenticationServiceProtocol{
    func userAuthRequest<T>(url: String, parameters: [String : Any], type: T.Type) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> where T : Decodable {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
            return Fail(error: URLError(.badURL)).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("en", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Language")
        
        let postData = parameters.map { "\($0)=\($1)" }
            .joined(separator: "&")
            .data(using: .utf8)
        request.httpBody = postData
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global())
            .map { data, response -> Data in
                print(data)
                       return data
                   }
            .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func logIn(){
        let parameters = [
            "mobile": phoneNumber,
            "password": password,
            "device_type": "iOS"
        ]
        isLoading = true
        service.userAuthRequest(url: Config.baseURL+"login", parameters: parameters, type: AuthenticationResponse.self)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] completion in
                self?.isLoading = false
                switch completion{
                case .finished:
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                    self?.errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
                    self?.showAlert = true
                }
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] returnedData in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                
                if !returnedData.status {
                    self.errorMessage = returnedData.message
                    self.showAlert = true
                 //   self.isAuthenticated = false
                   // UserManager.shared.clearUserData()
                    return
                }
                
                guard returnedData.data?.isActive != false else{
                    self.navigateToVerification = true
                    return
                }
                if returnedData.status{
                    self.isAuthenticated = true
                    if let token = returnedData.data?.accessToken{
                        UserManager.shared.saveToken(token)
                    }
                    if let userData = returnedData.data {
                        UserManager.shared.saveUser(userData)
                    }
                }else{
                    UserManager.shared.clearUserData()
                    self.errorMessage = returnedData.message
                    self.showAlert = true
                    self.isAuthenticated = false
                }
                if let data = returnedData.data{
                    self.userData = data
                }else{
                    self.errorMessage = returnedData.message
                    self.showAlert = true
                }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

but if there are any data in the textfields I get the backend messages , why when empty It be in completion failure and get this error

Print row response data as String, I guess you're receiving a HTML/XML error message that could tell you what went wrong. I don't know your API, but maybe you need to add the (Accept)Content-Type to tell you'd prefer JSON as response.

that's the backend returns when empty parameters :
{
"status": false,
"message": "The password field is required.",
"data": null
}

No, the error states you're receiving something starting with <, print the full response. Do not assume that what's supposed to be (as you expect the response) is as such (what is you real response).

@Larme
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600000228860> { URL: https:// the url with out the endpoint  } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
"Cache-Control" =     (
"no-cache, private"
);
Connection =     (
"Keep-Alive"
);
"Content-Encoding" =     (
br
);
"Content-Length" =     (
567
);
"Content-Type" =     (
"text/html; charset=UTF-8"
);
Date =     (
"Wed, 25 Sep 2024 12:32:32 GMT"
);
"Keep-Alive" =     (
"timeout=3, max=9"
);
Server =     (

""Content-Type" = ( "text/html; charset=UTF-8"": To me it's not responding in JSON, it might, but very unlikely. Instead of print(data), do print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)) You might be missing a header in your request stating you'd want a response in JSON format.

why the url without endpoint "login" when I post the empty data , while I posted wrong data now I get the url with endpoint and the backend message appeared , the problem when empty params

get this when printing string data:data , encoding,,,,
Optional("\n<html lang="ar">\n\n\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">\n\n    هين\n\n    \n    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">\n\n    \n    
the data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format

Because it's html and not json

how to fix it please ?

Once again, try to put the correct header in your request stating you want JSON response. Else, it might be a bug on your API or read the doc, or else we can't know Read the content of the HTML page, does your API allows what's your intending to do?

Just take the HTML and check in webView what it is saying. I think since you give empty data, the return value might be a new updated login form with the password error.
